# How to run PHP CLI command form wget?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, wget

I want to run a php cli command from wget but it doesn't work:

run.sh file:

```
wget -t 1 --timeout=40 -e "php file.php"
```

error:

```
wget: Invalid command --execute "php file.php"
```

The files "file.php" and "run.sh" are in the same directory.

Comment: @arkascha it is NOT a cron job, just two files in the same directory

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Question: why use wget if you want to execute a php command? Why not simply execute the command? What you specify simply is not a command wget understands. The `-e` flag is not to execute arbitrary commands.

Comment: @arkascha I want to run thousands asynchronous PHP commands with wget.

Comment: wget is for http link execution not php , simply use `php file.php` instead `wget -t 1 --timeout=40 -e "php file.php"`, or if you wan to exec wget then you have to pass link instead `wget `http://domian/path/file.php`

Comment: @Armen wget can execute localhost php files, I want to know if it is possible with cli (to run a lot of asynchronous PHP files with wget).

Comment: wget needs an url. If that is on localhost, fine. WEBget. I don't think you can run cli with it, nor do I understand why you would use wget for that. the -e option in wget is not an arbitairy execute command. https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: just try `wget http://localhost/path/file.php` of if you have virtual host created then `wget http://virtual_host_name/path/file.php`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. I can not using WGET for execution PHP CLI and I can use WGET with http:://localhost path.

Comment: `Yes, and most important: yo can simply use `php file.php` to execute a sceipt with your cli version of php. Also thousands of scripts, if you like.